# Find an index such that all partial sums are nonnegative

Tags: arrays, algorithm, indexing, integer

Given an array a[] of integers of arbitrary size N that sum to 0 (for example, a[] = {-1, 0, 5, 3, -9, 2}), does there always exists an index i ($0\le i\le N-1$) such that each partial sum $S_j = \sum_{k=i}^ j a_{k\pmod N}$ (with $N+i-1\ge j\ge i$) is nonnegative?

In the example a[] = {-1, 0, 5, 3, -9, 2} where $a_0 = -1, a_1 = 0, ... a_5 = 2$ (and we can check that $\sum_{k=0}^{5} a_k=0$), we can start from $i=5$ so that the partial sums $2, 2-1, 2-1+0, 2-1+0+5, 2-1+0+5+3, 2-1+0+5+3-9$ are all nonnegative.

If we can prove that such index $i$ always exists, what's an efficient algorithm to find the index $i$? There's an obvious $O(N^2)$ algorithm, but can we do it in $O(N)$? Thanks.

Note: this problem is somewhat similar to another problem: given an array of integers $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ (they don't have to add up to 0), find $\max_{0\le i\le j\le n}\sum_{k=i}^j a_k$. This can be solved in time $O(n)$ as follows:

```
int maxsum = INT_MIN;
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
    if (sum <= 0) { sum = a[i]; }
    else { sum += a[i]; }
    maxsum = max(sum, maxsum);
}
```

But in my original question, we are allowed to loop around, and we're required to find the index. So there are at least two differences between the two problems.

(Oops, LaTeX doesn't work on this site... that's why there are those dollars signs $ floating around...)

Here's my question at the math forum:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539923/finding-the-index-such-that-all-partial-sums-are-nonnegative

Answer (score 0):

code worth a thousand words.
it should be correct. I didn't actually run and check.

c code:

```
int getTheIndex(int* a,int length){
 int min=a[0];
 int mini=0;
 int sum=a[0];
 for(int t=1;t<length;t++){
  sum+=a[t];
  if(min<sum){
   min=sum;
   mini=t;
  }
 }
 return mini;
}
```